# How to choose number 5-10 in DESC MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I wanted to do 2 while loops, cause I have 2 tables. In the first table I wanted to have the first 5 ids

```
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM link WHERE `userid`= $uid ORDER by clicks DESC LIMIT 5";`
```

Don't mind Ik that the variable in the statement is insecure, so I gonna use a prepared statement later. But still, in the first while it should give out the first 5 ids, and in the second while id 5-10. What should the second $sql look like ?

Comment: Have a look at `OFFSET`

Comment: why not JOIN also seeing you're using 2 tables? question's a tad unclear. 2 loops could slow things down if none of your tables are (properly) indexed.

Comment: Use `LIMIT 5,5`. That first query could be `LIMIT 0,5`.  (before the comma is the number of rows to "skip".)  If both sets of rows are in the same response, we'd typically not run two separate queries, but just one query to get all the rows `LIMIT 0,10`, and handle the "break" at five rows in the fetch loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OFFSET like this :

`` SELECT * FROM link WHERE `userid`= $uid ORDER by clicks DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5 ``

Comment: You need to use backticks, not quotation marks. Your suggestion also maintains the possibility of SQL injection.

Comment: Actually didn't know that. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Second SQL look like this:

```
<?php
    ...
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM link WHERE userid = :uid ORDER by clicks DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(sql2);

    $stmt->execute(['uid ' => $uid]);
    ...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM link WHERE `userid`= '$uid' ORDER by clicks DESC LIMIT 5, 5";
```

this will give 5 records starting from record number 6 (record number 5 will not appear in the results)

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 loops on 1 query.  An additional query is not necessary.

For example in a `for` loop:

```
<?php
    $results = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n");

    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        echo $results[$i];
    }

    echo " / ";

    for ($i=5; $i<10; $i++) {
        echo $results[$i];
    }
    // yields: abcde / fghij
?>
```

Or same sample in a `while` loop:

```
<?php
    $results = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n");
    $i = 0;
    while($i < 5) {
        echo $results[$i];
        $i++;
    } 

    echo " / "; 

    while($i < 10) {
        echo $results[$i];
        $i++;
    } 
    // yields: abcde / fghij
?>
```